# Apache Tomcat 8 not starting within a docker container

Tags: apache, ubuntu, tomcat, docker, dockerfile

I am experimenting with Docker and am very new to it. I am struck at a point for a long time and am not getting a way through and hence came up with this question here...

Problem Statement:
I am trying to create an image from a docker file containing Apache and lynx installation. Once done I am trying to access tomcat on 8080 of the container which is in turn forwarded to the 8082 of the host. But when running the image I never get tomcat started in the container.

The Docker file

```
FROM ubuntu:16.10
#Install Lynx
Run apt-get update
Run apt-get install -y lynx

#Install Curl
Run apt-get install -y curl

#Install tools: jdk
Run apt-get update
Run apt-get install -y openjdk-8-jdk wget

#Install apache tomcat
Run groupadd tomcat
Run useradd -s /bin/false -g tomcat -d /opt/tomcat tomcat
Run cd /tmp
Run curl -O http://apache.mirrors.ionfish.org/tomcat/tomcat-    8/v8.5.12/bin/apache-tomcat-8.5.12.tar.gz
Run mkdir /opt/tomcat
Run tar xzvf apache-tomcat-8*tar.gz -C /opt/tomcat --strip-components=1
Run cd /opt/tomcat
Run chgrp -R tomcat /opt/tomcat
Run chmod -R g+r /opt/tomcat/conf
Run chmod g+x /opt/tomcat/conf
Run chown -R tomcat /opt/tomcat/webapps /opt/tomcat/work /opt/tomcat/temp opt/tomcat/logs

Run cd /opt/tomcat/bin

Expose 8080
CMD /opt/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh run && tail -f /opt/tomcat/logs/catalina.out
```

When the image is built I tried running the container by the two below methods

1. docker run -d -p 8082:8080 imageid tail -f /dev/null
   While using the above, container is running but tomcat is not started inside the container and hence not accessible from localhost:8082. Also I do not see anything if I perform docker logs longcontainerid
2. docker run -d -p 8082:8080 imageid /path/to/catalina.sh start tail -f /dev/null
   I see tomcat started when I do docker logs longconatainrid 
   While using the above the container is started and stopped immediately and is not running as I can see from docker ps and hence again not accessible from localhost:8082.

Can anyone please tell me where I am going wrong?

P.s. I searched a lot on the internet but could not get the thing right. Might be there is some concept that i am not getting clearly.

Comment: Why not use a reference Tomcat from https://hub.docker.com/_/tomcat/  ? and by the way (this is not your problem) , you should group your RUN in your Dockerfile, see https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at the [`docker run` command documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#cmd-default-command-or-options), the doc states that any command passed to the `run` will override the original CMD in your `Dockerfile`:

> As the operator (the person running a container from the image), you can override that CMD instruction just by specifying a new `COMMAND`

1/ Then when you run:

```
docker run -d -p 8082:8080 imageid tail -f /dev/null
```

The container is run with `COMMAND` `tail -f /dev/null`, the original command starting tomcat is **overridden**.

To resolve your problem, try to run:

```
docker run -d -p 8082:8080 imageid
```

and

```
docker log -f containerId
```

To see if tomcat is correctly started.

2/ You should not use the `start` argument with `catalina.sh`. Have a look at this [official tomcat Dokerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/tomcat/blob/4f193f544a7deb2dc95a33f8ea447c235c7d180a/8.0/jre8-alpine/Dockerfile), the team uses :

```
CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]
```

to start tomcat (when you use `start`, docker ends container at the end of the shell script and tomcat will start but **not** maintain a running process).

3/ Finally, why don't you use tomcat official image to build your container? You could just use the :

```
FROM tomcat:latest
```

directive at the beginning of your Dockerfile, and add you required elements (new files, webapps war, settings) to the docker image.

Comment: Thanks a lot François Maturel for the detailed reply.
1. I missed this concept and it resolved my issue.
2. I was aware of the second point but while running it with the Command statement overlooked it.
3. I could have used the Tomcat official image but was trying to play around and install lynx with the tomcat..so that I can understand that more than one application can be installed with the help of the dockerfile though it might not be the best practice. Hence I need to look more into multiple dockerfiles installing apps and preparing my environment.

Thanks again :)

Comment: @Arindam, you're welcome. If you wan't to play around docker and add more software / tweaks around tomcat, you could still use the official image and add your own stuff. This is also nice sometimes to create the container image from stratch to really understand the process ;)

Comment: @FrançoisMaturel @Arindam, could you provide more insight on Point 2) When we use `start ` . Tomcat will start but not maintain a running process. What does it mean ? Does our container will die ?

Comment: @JoshiYogesh when the `catalina.sh start` process ends, indeed your container will stop running. You won't be able to establish any tcp/udp connections. When using `run`, the `catalina.sh` process inside the container will live until you tell the docker container to stop. You will be able to establish tcp/udp connections.

Comment: @FrançoisMaturel Thanks, now got it.